# How to reduce spring boot jar size

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am struggling to reduce the size of my simple spring boot project. It contains just 3 classes but the size of bundled jar is 500 MB+. I tried thin launcher but somehow it gives the following error -

```
Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.2:repackage failed: A required class was missing while executing org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.2:repackage: org/springframework/util/function/ThrowingConsumer
```

I have worked with spring project before but not with aws SDK so trying to get my head around. Basically I just want to create a basic lambda function. If you have faced such problem, please guide me. Here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>au.com.agrifhm</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>abcd</name>
    <description>abcd</description>
    <properties>
        <aws.java.sdk.version>2.X.X</aws.java.sdk.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.520</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.120</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-launcher</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.30.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use container lambda which gives you 10GB of space?

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I would love to. I will explore that. but my core problem is why my jar is so big when m using just 3 classes. If I can fix that, that would be really helpful.

Comment: If you application contains only three classes, it must be its dependencies that are bloating the jar file. The output of `unzip -l your-application.jar` will show the size of each entry in the jar. Can you share that output, particularly the parts of it that show the jars in `BOOT-INF/lib`?

Comment: What benefit does Springboot - a server environment - bring to AWS Lambada - also a server environment?  Additionally, you're using AWS Java SDK v1 (SES) *and* what is basically *all* V2 libraries.  Why do you need both?

Comment: @stdunbar thanks boss. this is exactly the guidance I was looking for. I just copied some maven dependencies from example projects so there might be some issues with version. I was able to run a simple hello world lambda working. could you please suggest any online tutorial that you can recommend?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks Andy. I think this might be something to bundle spring boot with lambda functions. I will send the output of the command you suggested.

Comment: You may also want to look at [Spring Cloud Function](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function). It's the recommended way to run a Spring app on AWS Lambda.